# Yii model rules: only allow values specified in itemAlias

Tags: php, yii

As a longtime procedural programmer, I finally made the switch to OOP/MVC in combination with Yii. I don't regret it at all, but I have a question which may be obvious.

In my model, generated by GII, I define rules and aliasses replacing values. Now I want the 'currency' value to only allow input specified in the aliasses. Ofcourse I can do something like is_number, greater that 0 and smaller than 4, but in that case I will have to update my code all the time when a new currency is added. Is there an easier way to do the input validation based on the defined values?

```
<?PHP
class Affiliateprograms extends CActiveRecord
 {

 //define rules
 public function rules()
  {
  return array(array('currency', 'required'));
  }

 //set aliases
 public static function itemAlias($type,$code=NULL)
  {
  $_items = array('currency' => array('1' => 'US Dollar','2' => 'Euro','3' => 'Yen'));
  if (isset($code))
   return isset($_items[$type][$code]) ? $_items[$type][$code] : false;
  else
   return isset($_items[$type]) ? $_items[$type] : false;
  }

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the builtin `in` validator (actually a [`CRangeValidator`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CRangeValidator)).

```
array('currency','in','range'=>array_keys(self::itemAlias('???')));
```

You need to insert the right `$type` of course.

Side note: Please reconsider your indenation style - it's pretty unusual and makes your code hard to read ;)

Comment: Thank you, this has pointed me in te right direction. Instead of array_values, I figured out I need to use array_keys tho.